# How to get field mapping information in custom module?

Tags: 8, entities

I am trying to call `field_info_field_map()` in my DefaultForm.php . What is the right way? I am getting the following error:

> Error: Class 'Drupal\module_name\Form\Field' not found in
>   Drupal\module_name\Form\DefaultForm->module_name_settings_get_field_options()

The code I am using is as follow:

```
$fields = Field::fieldInfo()->getFieldMap();
```

the code i am trying to convert to d8

```
function mn_settings_get_field_options() {
  static $options = null;
  if (is_array($options)) {
    return $options;
  }
  $options = array();
  $fields = field_info_field_map();
  foreach ($fields as $field_name => $field_data) {
    if (isset($field_data['bundles']['node'])) {
      $node_types = $field_data['bundles']['node'];
      $options[$field_name] = $field_name . ' (In content types: ' . implode(', ', $node_types) . ')';
    }
  }
  asort($options);
  return $options;
}
```

Comment: Did you specify the class via `use` at the top of the file under namespace?

Comment: @Kevin i did specify use Drupal\field\Plugin\Core\Entity\FieldInstance;
use Drupal\field\Field; but still getting error . The reference to getFieldMap() is found in this link http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/drupal%21core%21modules%21field%21field.info.inc/function/field_info_field_map/8

Comment: That site is way outdated. Use only the official API docs.

Comment: @Kevin  this seems to do  the job <code>$fields =  \Drupal::entityManager()->getFieldMap();</code> but the  output array for field doesnt tell whether the bundle is node or other entity

Comment: Not sure what you're talking about, but drupalcontrib.org is not up to date, nor official as far as I know.

Comment: @kevin you suggestion helped .fields = \Drupal::entityManager()->getFieldMap(); did the job.

Comment: If that works for you, please mark the answer as accepted so others are also helped.

Comment: @kevin i finally got better solution. This query ; `code` 'select  name  from  config where name like 'field.field.node%';' `code` will give me all the field attached to the node.

Answer (score 2):

Looks one potential solution is to use is [EntityFieldManager::getFieldMap](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Entity!EntityFieldManager.php/function/EntityFieldManager%3A%3AgetFieldMap/8.2.x). See the [change log for this change](https://www.drupal.org/node/2260037).

Also, FYI:

> When working directly with an $entity, the field definitions (which include base and configurable fields) can be directly requested from the object with $entity->getFieldDefinitions() or $entity->getFieldDefinition($field_name)

Comment: i am still have problem with name space \Drupal::entityManager()->getFieldMap(); works but if i try entityManager ::getFieldMap(); it doesnt work! same with  EntityFieldManager::getFieldMap . I m using name space use Drupal\Core\Entity;

Comment: i have update the code  in the question , this is what i am trying to implement in D8

Comment: Calling `EntityFieldManager::getFieldMap()` doesn't work because `getFieldMap` is not a static method (http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php). `entityFieldManager` is a Drupal service called `entity_field.manager` and to call the function you should first ask for the service instance `\Drupal::service('entity_field.manager')->getFieldMap()`

Comment: @Eyal @kevin  how to get the entity type id  of the bundle , in D7  field map return array as field[bundles][node][0] => ''content type " . In D8 field map functions return like field[bundle][0]="content type" . I n my case i want to filter the bundle with entity id 'node'. `code` $fields = field_info_field_map();
  foreach ($fields as $field_name => $field_data) {
    if (isset($field_data['bundles']['node'])) {
      $node_types = $field_data['bundles']['node'];
      $options[$field_name] = $field_name . ' (In content types: ' . implode(', ', $node_types) . ')';
    }
  } `code`

Comment: Too much code for comments.

Comment: @Kevin though its same code as above in question

Comment: @AdityaJoshi you should read the documentation for the [EntityFieldManager::getFieldMap](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Entity!EntityFieldManager.php/function/EntityFieldManager%3A%3AgetFieldMap/8.2.x) and see [EntityFieldManager::getFieldMapByFieldType](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityFieldManager.php/function/EntityFieldManager%3A%3AgetFieldMapByFieldType/8.2.x) as an example usage. The returned array is as follows: `$field_data[ENTITY_TYPE][FIELD_NAME] = ['type' => FIELD_TYPE, 'bundles' => [BUNDLES...]]`

Comment: @Eyal i am getting the return array as you said , i have to figure out a way to filter field attached to node. in D7 the return array has order of entity-type=> bundle_name. the above function doesnt have this! This statement worked fine in d7 if (isset($field_data['bundles']['node'])) {} ! but in d8 it doesnt

Comment: FYI in D9 fields added via hook_entity_bundle_field_info() aren't currently returned from getFieldMap() see https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3045509

Answer (score 1):

The following DB query will give me list of all fields attached to node:

`select  name  from  config where name like 'field.field.node%';`

Comment: @eyal  finally  i got the solution.